# How to turn a system of sympy equations into matrix form

Tags: python, sympy

How do I turn a system of sympy equations into a matrix form?

For example, how do I turn a system like this:

```
equation_one = 4*a*x + 3*b*y
equation_two = 2*b*x + 1*a*y
```

Into a system like this:

```
matrix_form = ([equation_one, equation_two], [x, y])
```

That will return this:

```
[[4*a, 3*b], 
 [2*b, 1*a]]
```

Does a function like matrix_form() exist?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some searching, I found

```
sympy.linear_eq_to_matrix(equations, *symbols)
```

This has solved my problem.